# RVM demands username in interactive prompt during Ruby install

Tags: ruby, rvm, ansible, redhat

I am attempting to use Ansible to install RVM to install an updated version of Ruby on a remote (RedHat 6.x) system. I have tried two separate Ansible-RVM playbooks ([rvm/rvm1-ansible](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible) and [newmen/ansible-rvm](https://github.com/newmen/ansible-rvm)), but they both exhibit the same behavior: they both reach the step at which the playbook directs RVM to install Ruby, then stall until I cancel the process:

```
TASK: [ansible-rvm | installing Ruby as root]
*********************************
<HOST.DOMAIN.xyz>
<HOST.DOMAIN.xyz>
<HOST.DOMAIN.xyz> IdentityFile=/Users/USER/.ssh/private-key-file ConnectTimeout=10 PasswordAuthentication=no KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no ControlPath=/Users/USER/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey ControlMaster=auto ControlPersist=60s
<HOST.DOMAIN.xyz>
<HOST.DOMAIN.xyz> IdentityFile=/Users/USER/.ssh/private-key-file ConnectTimeout=10 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=KEY] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-KEY; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/USER/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-dir/command; rm -rf /home/USER/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-dir/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"'' PasswordAuthentication=no KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no ControlPath=/Users/USER/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey ControlMaster=auto ControlPersist=60s
^CERROR: interrupted
```

It appears that the cause is that RVM is demanding some kind of login information. When I SSH into the host in question to run RVM manually, I get a prompt `Username:`:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/6/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Enabling optional repository
Username: ^C
User interrupted process.
```

The above occurs regardless of whether or not the `rvm` command is run under `sudo`.

I have been unable to find any documentation as to what login/username RVM is requesting, nor any instructions as to flags or configuration I could apply in order to disable interactivity; in fact, I've yet to find any reference to this login prompt in conjunction with RVM at all. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Are you trying to do a system-wide installation of RVM or user-local? System-wide requires `sudo` access. Are you using the [installation commands](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) recommended by the RVM maintainers? In past conversations with them they recommended the user-local version of installing RVM.

Comment: I have no issues with rvm_io.rvm1-ruby on CentOS7. I first had to create /usr/local/bin for it to work though. Never asked me for a username.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that rvm is trying to install system requirements, and that requires to enter the sudo password.

I have fixed this in my fork of rvm1-ansible [here](https://github.com/jogaco/rvm1-ansible) in this [commit](https://github.com/jogaco/rvm1-ansible/commit/903f0e9c7bcb72dea37cbf60ce1a3b10facb1b2b)

Works for me in Ubuntu.

```
---
- name: Configure servers with ruby support for single user
  hosts: newservers
  become: yes

  roles:
    - { role: rvm_io.ruby,
        tags: ruby,
        rvm1_rubies: [2.3.3],
        rvm1_user: 'sudouser',
        rvm1_install_flags: '--auto-dotfiles --user-install',
        rvm1_install_path: '/home/{{ ansible_user }}/.rvm',
      }
```

Launch the task with a sudo user:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini ruby_script.yml --user sudouser --ask-sudo-pass
```